# Using JQuery etc. in TypeScript with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to require jquery via AMD in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763684/how-to-require-jquery-via-amd-in-typescript)

I created a project in `TypeScript`. I use `RequireJS`. Everything was working fine, until I need `JQuery`...

This is my files structure:

[image: File structure]

As you can see, I have `jquery-1.8.d.ts` file in the `modules` folder. The `.js` file for `jQuery` is inside the `lib` folder. When I import a module using the config file for `RequireJS`:

```
/// <reference path="../modules/require.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="AppMain.ts" />

require.config({
    baseUrl: '../',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery-1.8.3'
    },
    shim: {
        jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        }
    },
    name: "app/AppMain",
    out: "../!built/Test.js",
    optimize: "none"
});

require(['jquery', 'app/AppMain',
],
    ($, main) => {
        var appMain = new main.AppMain();
        appMain.run();
    });
```

... then it's imported in `JavaScript`. What to do if I want it inside `TypeScript`? I need to use `JQuery`, `JQueryStatic` and `JQueryPromise`, declared inside `.d.ts` file.

When I try simply import a new module, I get an error:

```
import JQueryExternal = module("../../../modules/jquery-1.8.d"); // error: The name does not exist in the currect scope. A module cannot be aliased to a non-module type
interface Test {
    MyMethod(): JQueryPromise; // here's a sample usage
}
```

In the beginning I thought that the path is wrong, but I tried to move it inside `classes` folder and next I imported it in such a way as the rest of classes. Same error:/

How to use `jQuery` in `TypeScript` in a way I want to? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely confused:

```
import JQueryExternal = module("../../../modules/jquery-1.8.d");
```

You don't import the definition file as a module in order to use it in TypeScript. Whether you are using AMD/RequireJS or Node.js style modules to import the eventual code, you always reference `d.ts` definition files in the same way, at the top of your document:

```
/// <reference path="YOUR-RELATIVE-PATH-HERE/jquery.d.ts" />
```

This doesn't make the library available in *JavaScript*, but it will make the definitions available as you write your *TypeScript*.

I'm working on a large application similar in scope to yours which makes heavy use of RequireJS and JQuery. I can't see any benefit to loading JQuery as a module. I just import the reference (as described above), and make sure my page loads JQuery (and any other libraries) first:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
... etc ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/client/libs/require.js" data-main="/content/client/pe.framework"></script>
```

Comment: I have to say, I like the simplicity of this, but isn't a benefit of requirejs it loads .js dependencies async ? (assuming web client js app)

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble with these two playing nicely together, so when I use requireJS with JQuery, I use a bundled version that loads them both.  I don't know typescript, though, so I'm not sure how helpful this will be.

Link to the bundle: https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery