# How to load jquery module in a typescript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, typescript-typings

To import the `jquery` library in my typescript project, I did the following.

- npm install typings --global
- typings install dt~jquery --global --save

Then in my typescript file, I did:

```
import {jquery as $} from 'jquery';
```

But the transcript compiler throws an error saying:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'jquery'.
```

[image]

What is that I am missing here? Why can the compiler not find the jquery module?

Typescript version I am using : `2.1.5`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763684/how-to-require-jquery-via-amd-in-typescript take a look here

Comment: @VladuIonut Could you let me know the mistake I am making?

Comment: import * as $ from "jquery"; try this syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to make the typescript compiler aware of your typings.

Any one of these should handle your issue. Don't do more than one or they may conflict.

- Add `"typings/index.d.ts"` to your `tsconfig.json`'s files array
- Use `///<reference path...` to pull in the jquery.d.ts file.
- Throw all of this away and use [@types](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/)

Comment: What is the difference between `typings` and `@types`?

Comment: They're very similar, they both pull from the same source ([DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)). Typings is a separate typings manager and you have to configure your typescript project to use its definitions. @types is integrated with npm and typescript 2.0+ and installing the @types/<project> npm module will be all you'll need to do for type info.